# ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 vs maven-cucumber-reporting

Tags: maven, build, maven-plugin, log4j2

jog4j2 works fine and reports generate without problems (log4j2.xml file is present in resources) but when I try to run "mvn clean install" I see an error

> [INFO] --- maven-cucumber-reporting:3.8.0:generate (cucumber-report) @ ---
>   ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

Comment: Please give more details about your environment and be specific about your question so that others may help you.

Comment: I try to make automatied tests, I use TestNG + Cucumber for this and log4j for logging. When I run tests via the runner it works without problems and logger woks too (log file is generated). But I wont to make cucumber html report, so I try to do this via the maven using command "mvn clean install". And in this case I have an error "No log4j2 configuration file found".